# Can I keep applications open after last window is closed?

Tags: 13.04

Is it possible to have a Mac OS behavior in Ubuntu 13.04 and let an app stay active / open after last window is closed?

Comment: Like minimize it to a tray?

Comment: Like Mac OS. Have it running even though no windows are open.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the "nohup" (no hangup) command when starting the command, you may get the behavior you want.  see the man page,

```
 man nohup
```

Putting an "&" after the command will run it in the background, but closing the terminal is likely to end that command, since the closing window generates the "hangup" signal, which may be the problem you have been having.

Comment: It's not a problem as such. More a desired feature. If possible.